# How to use Gurobi libraries in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++, gurobi

I am trying to use gurobi in OMNet++. I have included `gurobi_c++.h` and in order to detect this file, I have already told the compiler where it can find it and the libraries. To do so, I went to Makemake options, custom, Makefrag and added two lines: `EXTRA_OBJS += -LC:/gurobi701/win32/lib` and `CFLAGS += -IC:/gurobi701/win32/include`. The first contains the path to gurobi C++ libraries and second contains the path to header file `gurobi_c++.h`. I also added the path to the include file in the `Includes` section in `Path and symbols` part for GNU C++ and path to libraries to `Library Paths`.

Despite all these, when I compile it says `undefined reference to` error for all functions used from `gurobi_c++.h`. I can see that it detects `gurobi_c++.h`, but I still have those errors.

Any ideas on what may cause the problem?

contents of bin folder:

[image]

contents of lib folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with `gurobi_c++` library file. Change `EXTRA_OBJS` into:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -LC:/gurobi701/win32/lib -lgurobi_c++
```

assuming that the library is called `libgurobi_c++.a` or `libgurobi_c++.dll`.

Comment: Where can I find that `.dll` file? It has `gurobi70.dll` in `bin` folder. But I do not see `libgurobi_c++.dll`. In lib folder there are all `.lib` files.

Comment: I don't have `gurobi`. Could you show content of `lib` dir, as well as `bin`?

Comment: I have the screen shots in the post for you. In lib folder there are different `.lib` files that each is for different Visual Studio versions with different options like /MT, /MD /MDD

Comment: Try to use: `EXTRA_OBJS += -LC:/gurobi701/win32/bin -lgurobi70` or  `EXTRA_OBJS += -LC:/gurobi701/win32/bin -lgurobi70 -lcurl -laes70`. By the way: are you sure that `gurobi` supports GCC?

Comment: No! But when I changed compiler from GCC for OMNet++ to MinGW and compiled, all errors are gone but one. It now does not detect omnet.h. Then I changed the compiler back to GCC for OMNet++. Now it says `no rule to make target 'all'`. The code text is different from previous. It detects member functions of objects of classes.

Comment: I strongly suggest using GCC for OMNeT++. Did you clean a project after changing back to GCC for OMNeT++ compiler? What errors are displayed for `-lgurobi70 -lcurl -laes70` ?

Comment: Still the same errors! Now that I am back to GCC for omnet++, the previous errors are have come back even for -lgurobi70 -lcurl -laes70. It is said in gurobi website that it is needed to link with gurobi C library as well which is gurobi70.lib.

Comment: I'm afraid that `gurobi70.lib` is for VS, not for GCC.